# Is caulk referred to as silicone caulk?

Tags: caulk, silicone, terminology

I know there is a difference between silicone and caulk?

Sometimes I see caulk referred to as silicone caulk which makes me think it is silicone or a type of silicone.  Is it correct to use the term silicone caulk and why is it called so if its different from silicone?

Comment: Did the term caulk exist prior to silicone?

Answer (score 2):

Some caulk is based on silicone rubber. Many non-caulk products are also based on silicone.

Lots of caulk is based on other things.

Latex, polyurethane, moss, oakum...